# Change block comments for JSX in webstorm

Tags: webstorm, reactjs

In webstorm, jsx has all the same colors & stylings as javascript, which is great. However, the block comments don't adjust to jsx `/* */` vs. `{/* */}`.

I have tried removing `*.jsx` as a registered javascript pattern in the `File Types` preferences & making jsx its own file type, but then I lose all the custom colors & styling. Is there a way to adjust the block comment characters on a per-pattern basis while having the styling refer to the pure javascript rules?

Comment: Currently version support this feature.

Comment: @Everettss - how?  2 years later and I currently have 2016.2.4 but I have still have the issue, if i select one or more lines of jsx code, it trys to comment by applying {/* */} which breaks everything.  For instance:

                                    {/*rowSelectionType="single"*/}
                                    {/*height={500}*/}

Comment: @schmoopy I don't remember version when they add this feature. But in current version 2017.2.4 it works fine.

Comment: @Everettss - oic ... i am using 2016.2.4 on mac and current on others -- that explains it --- thank you :-)

Answer (score 5):

No. Please vote for [WEB-16439](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16439) - a request for JSX comments support

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty convenient/hacky way to do that - add a live template to your Javascript group in `Editor -> Live templates` with content like this:

```
{/*$SELECTION$*/}
```

then, in your code, select any react code, press `⌥⌘T` and type the first letter of your template's abbreviation.

Comment: Did you mean a special `surround` group?